# Windows task sceduler command to uncheck "Do not store password.The task will only have access to local resources"

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating a task in windows Task Scheduler via command line using following commmand -

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONSTART /TN "MyTask" /TR "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.exe" /RL HIGHEST /NP
```

[image: Do not store password]

Is there any parameter to **schtasks /create** to uncheck *"do not store password"* under *"user is logged in or not"?*.

[image: Stop task]

Also, is there any parameter to uncheck *"Stop task if it runs longer than"*

I tried following [Microsoft Task Scheduler Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx). But, couldn't get the result needed.

Comment: I would guess that if you provide a username and password (/ru and /rp options) then the "do not store password" option will be automatically turned off.

Comment: I added /RU ADMINISTRASTOR /RP. I was prompted for password."Error: The user name and password is incorrect" message appears even after giving correct username & password.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `/NP` from the command. I can get the desired output.